# How to share response data across multiple suites?

Tags: testing, cypress

Let's say we have the following suite:

```
describe('Devices', () => {
    describe('Master Data Set-Up', () => {
        it('should create the device if necessary', () => {
            cy.createDevice()
                its('body.id')
                .as('deviceId');
        });
    });
    describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
        it('should allow to send data to device', () => {
            cy.get('@deviceId').then((deviceId) => {
                cy.sendData(deviceId, 'Some Data');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

So, we have a set up suite that creates master data. This is a simplified version, actually it contains a couple of it specs and I'd like to keep it like that because it's better to read in the Cypress output.

Then, there is the actual test suite that want's to use data that has previously been created. In this case a server generated id that should be used for another REST call.

This is assuming, that `cy.createDevice` and `cy.sendData` are custom commands available that internally use `cy.request`.

When running that, `cy.get('@deviceId')` fails because aliases are not shared across describe blocks AFAIK. I tried to use `let deviceId` but it's undefined as it is not yet available when the test specs are processed.

What is a proper way to do this?

Comment: Hi. Beside global variable which is an anti-pattern, this post could be helpful: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1392#issuecomment-660588861

Comment: May be try using writeFile https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html and readFile https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html#Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first thanks to Aloysius and Arek for their answers. But I had the gut feeling that there must be some easier way to do this that writing an Id to a file.

As I mentioned before, I had issues with my first attempt to use a global variable:

> I tried to use let deviceId but it's undefined as it is not yet
> available when the test specs are processed.

I really wanted to understand, why this did not work and did some console debugging.

I added a console log:

```js
describe('Devices', () => {

    console.log('Loading test suites...')

    (...)
});
```

When running the tests, I saw the log output *twice*, once after the first describe block where the device id was stored and then a second time after the master data was written.

Actually, I found out that this issue was cause by the following known Cypress issue:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2777

After setting the baseUrl, it actually works:

```js
describe('Devices', () => {
    let deviceId;

    before( () => {
        Cypress.config('baseUrl', Cypress.env('system_url'))
        cy.visit('/');
    })

    describe('Master Data Set-Up', () => {
        it('should create the device if necessary', () => {
            cy.createDevice()
                .its('body.id')
                .then((id) => {
                    deviceId = id;
                });
        });
    });
    describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
        it('should allow to send data to device', () => {
            cy.sendData(deviceId, 'Some Data');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will be better solution, as cypress is asynchronous so it's better to write it on file and read it

```
describe('Devices', () => {
describe('Master Data Set-Up', () => {
    it('should create the device if necessary', () => {
        cy.createDevice()
        ......
        cy.writeFile('deviceId.txt', body.id)
            
    });
});
describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
    it('should allow to send data to device', () => {
        cy.readFile('deviceId.txt').then((device_id) => {
            cy.sendData(device_id, 'Some Data');
        })
            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This can fail if tests run in parallel. Better to get the id in a `before()`. Also the pattern you want for saving is `cy.createDevice().its('body.id').then(id => cy.writeFile('deviceId.txt', id))`.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote for @ArekKhatry's idea, but to be safe I would obtain the the id in a `before()`. If you ever run tests in parallel, grabbing data from one test to use in another would be flaky.

Note that running `cy.createDevice().its('body.id')` in the `before()` still gives you the same test coverage as running inside `it()`, i.e it tests that the request succeeds and the return value has an id.

The file should be written to `cypress/fixtures`, otherwise it will write to the project root causing untidy pollution of the file structure.

Also, the id is returned from `cy.request()` as a number, but must be stringifyed in order to write to a text file.

Here's my variant

```js
describe('Devices', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.createDevice()           
      .its('body.id')
      .then(id => {
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/deviceId.txt', id.toString());
        cy.log(`Created device: ${id}`);
      });
  });

  describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
    it('should allow to send data to device', () => {

      cy.fixture('deviceId')               // can use simpler cy.fixture here
        .then(device_id => {               // returned as a string here
          const id = parseInt(device_id);  // may need to parse to number?   
          cy.sendData(id, 'Some Data');
        })
    });
  });
});
```